# Defining and calling a C++ function of a specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-specialization

I am currently learning C++ in-depth, and I have come across something that has stumped for a couple hours now. **Why is it when I make a template and then specialize it, that I can't call or define that function for the specialized version?** The compiler complains, and I have scoured Google for a possible hint as to what I am doing wrong, but to no avail. I am very sure it is something very simple that I am overlooking:

```
template <typename T>
class C { };

//specialization to type char
template <>
class C <char> 
{
  public:
    void echo();
};

//compiler complains here
template <>
void C <char> :: echo() 
{
  cout << "HERE" << endl;
}
```

> error: template-id ‘echo<>’ for ‘void C::echo()’ does not match
>   any template declaration

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/3SwUc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [template-id does not match any template delcaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694181/template-id-does-not-match-any-template-delcaration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//specialization to type char
template <>
class C <char>
{
  public:
    void echo();
};

//template<>  <----- don't mention template<> here
void C <char> :: echo()
{
  cout << "HERE\n";
}
```

P.s. Never say `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. [What is the C++ iostream endl fiasco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco)

Comment: Thanks @Rob! Last question, why does the function "echo()" not need a template specifier?

Comment: @jrd1, because `echo()` is not a `template` function by itself. It's a member method of a `template class`.

Answer (score 0):

Robᵩ's answer fixes the issue. It will be good to know more about the reason.

From [Explicit (full) template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

> **Members of specializations**
>
> When defining a member of an explicitly specialized class template
> outside the body of the class, the syntax template<> is not used,
> except if it's a member of an explicitly specialized member class
> template, which is specialized as a class template, because otherwise,
> the syntax would require such definition to begin with
> template required by the nested template.